# Auto-hide notification bar while apps are opened

Tags: notification-bar

With a custom launcher, you can auto-hide the notification bar on the home screen and swipe down to make it re-appear. However, when you open an app, the notification bar re-appears.

Is there any way to hide the notification bar on a non-rooted device?

Comment: For the ADB approach, it's mentioned on [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/199594/44325).

Answer (score 3):

**This feature is known as "[immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat#44-immersive)" and was first introduced in Android 4.4 KitKat.** It allows the app to hide the notification/status bar and even the navigation bar.

For the official method, the developers of the app need to implement this feature on their app. Though, some ROMs may also provide this feature built-in, sometimes also known as "expanded desktop mode", e.g. [CyanogenMod/LineageOS](https://www.androidpolice.com/2012/10/29/cyanogenmod-now-has-an-expandable-desktop-feature-that-hides-navigation-buttons-and-the-status-bar/), [OnePlus](https://community.oneplus.com/thread?id=96330).

Otherwise, some 3rd-party apps may help to force immersive mode in all apps:

- Search for ["Immersive mode" keyword on Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=immersive%20mode&c=apps).
- (For rooted devices) Xposed Framework with [Immerse Me](https://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.immerseme) module. Follow the instruction on [phoneArena.com](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Got-KitKat-Heres-how-to-force-immersive-mode-on-apps-and-throughout-the-entire-UI_id53846) for step-by-step installation.

---

Note that by using these apps, the keyboard may not work properly.

From [BGR](http://bgr.com/2014/03/20/android-immersive-mode-how-to/),

> Due to some security features in Android, users will not have access to the keyboard in many apps while in immersive mode.

From WonderHowTo

> Beware that your keyboard may not work in Immersive Mode, which is why having the toggle in the notification shade is so handy.