# Immersive mode in Termux?

Tags: terminal, termux, immersive-mode

How can I enable immersive/fullscreen mode in Termux?

I want to hide the bars at the top and bottom of the screen so that the entire screen displays the terminal.

In summary, I'm looking for *either* a configuration option for enabling fullscreen mode in Termux, without reconfiguring (or rooting) my device and without connecting an external device, *or* an explanation of what happened to the fullscreen option mentioned in some parts of the documentation, if it has been removed.

Answer (score 4):

I could have sworn immersive mode was a feature of Termux... You can still use immersive mode via ADB (or root, if you have that).

Hide both status and navigation bar: `adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.full=com.termux`

Hide status bar only: `adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.status=com.termux`

Hide navigation bar only: `adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.navigation=com.termux`

Turn off immersive mode: `adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.off=com.termux`

Comment: I've seen references to a fullscreen option while Googling, but also references to it being removed. Not sure what's going on with it. Hoping not to have to resort to adb... a setting in a dotfile would be ideal. Have a virtual +1, apparently I lack the rep to give you a real one.

Comment: Didn't work for me for some reason. Android 11 on realme5pro

Answer (score 3):

Since v0.107 (around Feb 2021), the fullscreen mode was added back with a fix to the Extra Keys issue. This should be configured manually through the property file.

From [Termux Wiki - Terminal Settings](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Terminal_Settings)

> The Termux terminal can be configured by creating the file `~/.termux/termux.properties`. This file uses a simple `key=value` property syntax and allows configuring the properties listed below.
>
> After changing the properties file the changes will take effect either by executing `termux-reload-settings` or by restarting the Termux app (closing all sessions and starting the app again).
>
> #### FullScreen Mode
>
> v0.107 added option to enable fullscreen mode by specifying:
>
> ```
> fullscreen = true
> ```
>
> Note: It is likely that with fullscreen enabled, the Extra Keys view may no longer be visible. To fix, enable this workaround:
>
> ```
> use-fullscreen-workaround = true
> ```
>
> *Fullscreen may not work well for all devices so consider it unstable for now.*

---

Related pull request and discussion: [#1911 - Implement full screen and add FullScreenWorkAround to fix ExtraKeysView](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/pull/1911)

Answer (score 2):

The fullscreen mode was removed in December 2017 due to the claim of complication with the multi-window and translucent status bar & navigation bar.

This was reported in [#507 - Fullscreen / immersive mode option is gone](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/507)

> I have noticed that fullscreen option was missing, I have looked at recent commits and it looks that it was removed from sources.
>
> <sup>kracejic - Dec 14, 2017</sup>

---

> Since it hasn't been mentioned why it was removed, here's the [commit](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/commit/de4f334e24a0676aa21d577f229dfaa4f595f9a0)
>
> > **Remove the fullscreen setting**
> > Trying to use fullscreen doesn't work well in a multi-windowed world
> > and makes using translucent navigation and status bars more complicated.
>
> [<sup>hyperpallium - Jul 28, 2018</sup>](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/507#issuecomment-408579387)

Answer (score -1):

Volume Up+K → variant to toggle extra keys view

Reference : https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Touch_Keyboard

Comment: Hi, after reading the wiki, I'm not sure if this is what the question asked. This looks like showing/hiding the "extra keys" row, while the question is asking about making the Termux fullscreen (without status bar & navigation bar).